# Why is this circuit not limiting current?

Tags: power-supply, current-limiting

This is a 15V voltage regulator from Art of Electronics (page 694), and it is supposed to limit the output current to 1A.
However, when driving load impedance (R7) low enough, I am getting much higher current than this. Any ideas where could be the problem?

My final goal is to build power supply with a (preferably adjustable) current limiter.
[image]

Comment: It looks like the Q2 collector is not connected to Q1 base.

Comment: Did you build this or simulate it?  And can the 2n2222 really handle 1 A, and a dissipation of 5 W (20 V - 15 V)*1 A?  I don't think so.

Comment: @G36 - Good eye!  But would the dot be there without a connection?

Comment: @G36 it is actually connected, it just looks like it is not

Comment: @SteveSh Just a simulation, I've picked random transistor, I will try a different one

Comment: @SteveSh Changed to 15A 60V transistors, still the same problem

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/yl2wv8o5

Comment: @G36 Perfect, I think this is going to be my go-to simulator now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the simulator model for the U2 amplifier doesn't include a current limit,
the intended effect of Q2 is defeated.   Put a series resistor
in the output, between the C1 and collector connections, to
get a real current-limit effect.

Simulators depict real devices, but aren't (internally) as
complicated as reality.  As others have pointed out, 2N2222
won't carry the intended current.

Comment: Seems like the problem was really with the amplifier, after swapping for another one the limiting is working. Thank you.